# add a round reinforcement around the edge

Tags: edges

I wan't to do a box with rounded edges, so I try to use wireframe + subdivision surface or skin but it doesn't work, can you help me?

[image: box around statue]

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for Bevel. You can Bevel your Mesh in Edit Mode by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, or you can just use the Bevel Modifier:

[image: Bevel]